# iPhone 5S vibrating constantly when I view a message

Tags: iphone, messages, crash

My iPhone 5S (iOS 9.2) is having the following problem: it can receive text messages and iMessages as normal, but when I view them my phone vibrates constantly until I stop viewing them, and moreover it doesn't consider the message to have been read. So far, my only attempt at fixing this is turning it off and back on, but this hasn't helped.

(Possibly related: over the last couple of days, apps have been quitting very frequently. I only bring this up because prior to the last two days, I've had no problems with my phone.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few more things that you can try to perform.

1. You can try to restart the device by holding both the home/sleep and the wake button for a few second until the Apple logo appears on the screen. And the phone restart.
2. Another option is to perform the restore of the phone. You need only to perform a backup using iTunes and then restore the iPhone from the last backup available on iTunes.

If these two options doesn't resolve your problem. You can ask assistance in a Apple Store center because clearly this is a problem the shouldn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more likely about software issue. Did you upgrade your iPhone 5s to latest version? Also you can backup your files on iCloud or iTunes, then remove all data and restore. Maybe the situation will be disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

I had it happen when I had no space left. Try clearing a few files and see if it clears